# How to stream an AI.JSX response with Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, jsx, server-sent-events

I am writing a small REST API with Node.js and Express, and I'm using AI.JSX with the OpenAI API. The AI.JSX docs provide an example of how to use [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to stream a response within the context of a Next.js application, and using a Vercel Edge Function:

https://docs.ai-jsx.com/tutorials/aijsxTutorials/part5-nextjs#the-aijsx-edge-function

The above uses the function [toStreamResponse](https://github.com/fixie-ai/ai-jsx/blob/main/packages/ai-jsx/src/stream/index.ts#L130), which creates/returns a new response object. This approach therefore does not integrate with Express, which expects you to work with the existing response object available in the route handler. How can I tie these two approaches together? I've tried using the [toTextStream](https://github.com/fixie-ai/ai-jsx/blob/main/packages/ai-jsx/src/stream/index.ts#L182) function:

```
routes.post("/chat-stream", async (req, res) => {
  const { system = "", user = "" } = req.body || {};

  if (!user) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
    return;
  }

  const RequestEl = getRequestEl(user, system);

  const stream = toTextStream(RequestEl);
  const reader = stream.getReader();

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
  res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  res.flushHeaders();

  const pump = () => {
    reader
      .read()
      .then(({ value, done }) => {
        if (done) {
          res.end();
          return;
        }

        res.write(value);
        pump();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        if (!res.headersSent) {
          res.status(500);
        }
        res.end();
      });
  };

  pump();
});
```

Using the above, I can see a response streaming back in Chrome dev tools, but the client-side AI.JSX-provided React hook does not report any data received. In other words, this:

```
const { error, current, fetchAI } = useAIStream({});
```

Always reports that both `error` and `current` are null.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the easiest thing was to simply pull the code from `toStreamResponse` directly into my Express app and use a stream pipeline (althought I'm not sure why the any is required in the pipeline call):

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { toEventStream } from "ai-jsx/stream";
import { createRenderContext } from "ai-jsx";
import {
  ChatCompletion,
  SystemMessage,
  UserMessage,
} from "ai-jsx/core/completion";
import { JSX } from "ai-jsx/jsx-runtime";
import { pipeline } from "stream/promises";

const routes = Router();

const getRequestEl = (user: string = "", system: string = ""): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <ChatCompletion>
      <SystemMessage>{system}</SystemMessage>
      <UserMessage>{user}</UserMessage>
    </ChatCompletion>
  );
};

routes.post("/chat-stream", async (req, res) => {
  const { system = "", user = "" } = req.body || {};

  if (!user) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
    return;
  }

  const RequestEl = getRequestEl(user, system);

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
  res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  res.flushHeaders();

  const renderResult = createRenderContext().render(RequestEl, {
    stop: () => false,
    map: (x) => x,
  });

  const eventStream = toEventStream(renderResult)
    .pipeThrough(
      new TransformStream({
        transform(streamEvent, controller) {
          controller.enqueue(`data: ${JSON.stringify(streamEvent)}\n\n`);
        },
      })
    )
    .pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream());

  pipeline(eventStream as any, res)
    .then(() => {
      res.end();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      if (!res.headersSent) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      res.end();
    });
});

export default routes;
```